# Cakephp 3.4 - How to validated associated relation data?

Tags: validation, cakephp, cakephp-3.x

For Example I have Club table and Club detail tables. Club table has many details.

And My form control is like below:

```
$this->Form->control('name');
$this->Form->control('club_payment_settings.0.no_of_account');
$this->Form->control('club_payment_settings.0.actual_rate');
$this->Form->control('club_payment_settings.1.no_of_account');
$this->Form->control('club_payment_settings.1.actual_rate');
$this->Form->control('club_payment_settings.2.no_of_account');
$this->Form->control('club_payment_settings.2.actual_rate');
```

And in controller written code as bellow:

```
$club = $this->Clubs->patchEntity($club, $this->request->getData(), [
    'associated' => [
        'ClubPaymentSettings' => [
            'validate' => 'default'
        ],
    ]
]);
```

How can I validate in Model `validationDefault()`? I am trying to do as follow in my `ClubsTable.php` file:

```
public function initialize(array $config)
    {
        parent::initialize($config);
        $this->setTable('clubs');
        $this->setPrimaryKey('id');

        $this->addBehavior('Timestamp');
        $this->hasMany('ClubPaymentSettings', [
             'foreignKey' => 'club_id',
             'joinType' => 'LEFT'
        ]);
       
    }
public function validationDefault(Validator $validator)
{
    $validator
        ->integer('id')
        ->allowEmpty('id', 'create');
    $validator
        ->requirePresence('name', true)
        ->notEmpty('name');

    $settingValidator = new Validator();
    $settingValidator->requirePresence('no_of_account', true);
    $settingValidator->requirePresence('actual_rate', true);

    $validator->addNestedMany('club_payment_settings', $settingValidator);
}
```

Comment: Please check the code again that you've posted and your description, in `patchEntity` you are referring to `ClubPaymentSettings`, and the property that you are setting however is called `detail`, which would default to a model named `Details`. If you have configured the `ClubPaymentSettings` to use the property name `detail`, then please explain that in your question, and just to be sure, show the association setup of your `ClubsTable`.

Comment: bake model ClubPaymentSettings, there is validation for that table

Comment: Yes that working. I made rules in ClubPaymentSettings. But one more thin, I can apply condition on rules in ClubPaymentSettings? 
For example
In clubsTable I have on dropdown (Option1, Option2), Based on that value ClubPaymentSettings rules are applied. 

If I choose option 1 then Only some fields required to validate and not others and vice versa